smooth atlas for torus from covering
Let $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2 =: T^2.$ For $x \in T^2$, let $U_x$ be an open neighborhood s.t.
$1.\ p^{-1}(U_x) = \dot\cup_{j \in \mathbb{Z}^2} V_{x,j}$, with $V_{x,j} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open;
$2. p|_{V_{x,j}} : V_{x,j} \to U_x$ is an homeomorphism.
Let $h_{x,j} = (p|_{V_{x,j}})^{-1} : U_x \to V_{x,j}$.
How can I show that the set of all $h_{x,j} \ \forall x \in T^2, \forall j \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ is a smooth atlas for $T^2$ ?
I get that the transition maps are homeomorphisms, but I have no idea how to show that they are diffeomorphisms. I guess that I have to work with the torus as a quotient space, since it's how it is defined in the exercise.

You say that you "get that the transition maps are homemorphisms". How did you get this? I ask because I would presume one gets this by writing down a formula for each transition map, and observing that the formula defines a homeomorphism. But in that case one should also be able to observe that the same formula (if it is correct) defines a diffeomorphism.

they are homeomorphisms because they are defined as composition of the $p|V{x,j}$ and their inverses (e.g. we define for some $x \in T^2, h_{ij} = (p|V{x,j}^{-1} \circ p|V{x,i}$ )

sorry I don't know why the latex code stays like this...

Your double subscripts are causing that. Just don't bother with a subscript after the restriction symbol. For example, just write p|V_{x,j}

The piece you are missing is that each transition map is the restriction of a deck transformation of the covering map $p : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 / \mathbb Z^2$. There is one deck transformation associated to each $(m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2$, and it is the translation map on $\mathbb R^2$ given by the formula
$$(x,y) \mapsto (x+m,y+n)
$$
This formula clearly defines a global homeomorphism and diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R^2$. When you restrict it to get an overlap map $h_{ij}$ from one open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ onto another, that restricted map is therefore also a homeomorphism and a diffeomorphism.

Thank you very much I hadn’t thought of it that way !
